# Unable to capture data on onrowselection in datatable LWC

Tags: apex, javascript, lightning-web-components, json, javascript-controller

Unable to capture selected rows details in LWC datatable, here is code
On selection passing selectedData is showing duplicate data in alert, I need to populate selected rows details(selectedData) in new table after capturing.

If I select 3 records,R1,R2,R3, it is duplicating like R1R1R2R1R2R3, How to remove this diplicate.

It is producing array of jsons like [{R1}{R1}{R2}{R1}{R2}{R3}]

*HTML code:*

```
<lightning-datatable 
   key-field="id"data={data} 
   columns={columns} 
   onrowselection= {selectedRowHandler}> 
</lightning-datatable>
```

*JS code:*

```
import { LightningElement,api,track,wire } from 'lwc';
import getProds from '@salesforce/apex/MM_ProdsInfo.getProducts';
    export default class GetProdsData extends LightningElement {

@track data = [];
selectedData = []; // will pass selected records into new table view
@track error;
@wire(getProds)
    wiredProducts({
        error,
        data
    }) {
        if (data) {
            this.data = data;
} else if (error) {
            this.error = error;
        }
    }


    selectedRowHandler(event){
    const selectedRows = event.detail.selectedRows; 
     for ( let i = 0; i < selectedRows.length; i++ ){             
                if ( !this.selectedData.includes(selectedRows[i].id) )
                    this.selectedData =[...this.selectedData, selectedRows[i]];
           }
           alert('@@:::NEW DATA:::'+JSON.stringify(this.selectedData));
        }
```

Comment: did you event is fired? you missed in `{` in your html for  `onrowselection= selectedRowHandler}` i think it's typo error.

Comment: Yes, it typo over here. It is firing, unable to assign selected rows into selectedData

Comment: why did u declare `selectedData ` twice?  did you check console.log(selectedRows[i].id) ?

Comment: Yes, checked in logs. Data is getting duplicated as stated for every selection it is appending before selected records data as well. Here is the logs appear like below

Comment: Total Selected Records: [{"Id":"01tA00000033yWUIAY","Name":"Test prodName 1","ProductCode":"57204"},{"Id":"01tA00000033yWUIAY","Name":"Test prodName 1","ProductCode":"57204"},{"Id":"01tA00000033yWWIAY","Name":"Test prodName 2","ProductCode":"57210"},{"Id":"01tA00000033yWUIAY","Name":"Test prodName 1","ProductCode":"57204"},{"Id":"01tA00000033yWWIAY","Name":"Test prodName 3","ProductCode":"57210"},{"Id":"01tA00000033yWYIAY","Name":"Test prodName 3","ProductCode":"57212"}]

Answer (score 1):

`onrowselection` is fired on *every* row selection passing *all* selected rows each time. This is why you're getting duplicates.

That is I believe is something that you see and what you're trying to filter out by

```
if ( !this.selectedData.includes(selectedRows[i].id) ) 
    this.selectedData =[...this.selectedData,     selectedRows[i]];
}
```

The problem is that you're trying to check id only, while your list contains objects. So you can either try and check for the whole object like this

```
if ( !this.selectedData.includes(selectedRows[i]) ) 
        this.selectedData =[...this.selectedData,     selectedRows[i]];
    }
```

Or create a mapped array to store data and check against it

```
import { LightningElement,api,track,wire } from 'lwc';
import getProds from '@salesforce/apex/MM_ProdsInfo.getProducts';
    export default class GetProdsData extends LightningElement {

@track data = [];
_selectedData = {} ; // will pass selected records into new table view
@track error;
@wire(getProds)
    wiredProducts({
        error,
        data
    }) {
        if (data) {
            this.data = data;
} else if (error) {
            this.error = error;
        }
    }

    get selectedData() {
        return Object.values(this._selectedData)
    } 


selectedRowHandler(event){
const selectedRows = event.detail.selectedRows; 
 for ( let i = 0; i < selectedRows.length; i++ ){             
        this._selectedData[selectedRows[i].id] = selectedRows[i] 
       alert('@@:::NEW DATA:::'+JSON.stringify(this.selectedData));
    }
```

Comment: Instead of on row selection Action, I have placed the logic into button click. After selection of records on click of button, Records are read so no duplicates are read.